# Using DataTable in UI layer instead of entities

Tags: c#, ado.net, datatable, data-access-layer

My basic 3 layered application consists of a DAL that talks to my BLL and BLL interacts with UI..

Until now i was using the old fashioned way of building the DAL with datareaders and update/insert commands. This has worked well because most of my needs where to read.

Now i need more and more to update database info and check some basic concurrency. I am thinking of using datatables to make my UI more flexible in editing and persisting data in db tables.

Now i am having a `List<InventoryItem>` in my UI and whenever i need i am sending this list to BLL->DAL to make my changes.

In my mind i think that i will have to make my BLL return datatable to UI in order to make my UI easier to respond to updates?

My main issue is how to logically bind the 3 layer logic (UI-BLL-DAL) with the advantages of DataAdapter/DataSets/DataTables model...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems proper at first, but doing it will simply destroy the layered architecture. With carrying typed datasets (`datatable`) up to `UI`, you are simply enabling the `UI` to use `CRUD` operations directly. Then there is no need to use other layers.

This will simply destroy the abstraction.

Use of an N-layer architecture is a choice, whether to use it or not depends on your requirements. Maybe, first you need to decide whether you really need it; and unless you can come up with a proper reasoning, you do not need to use it.

Comment: I see. Look i need the layered approach. I may have simple applications but they are quite a few addressing different domain issues. So i want to have a solid DAL and BLL and apply my UI need accordingly (Forms, WPF,WCF e.t.c). As i understand if i need the domain approach / layered , i should either go traditionaly with datareaders e.tc. or switch to ORM?

Comment: IMHO, switching to an ORM maybe helpful depending on the size and requirements of the project instead of employing datareader approach.

Comment: The siz is not big this time. One table read/write and read from 5-6 tables to get the correct data to write....Just wanted to explore whats happening regarding approaches. I am thinking that its either datareaders and ORM...

Comment: then the total number of tables in the database is limited to 6 at maximum?

Comment: Yeap , one in SQl Server and the others in an AS400 DB2, used for selecting values and prepare data for the sql server table

Comment: AS400 DB2 is the keyword here; I would definitely advise you to go with datareaders.

Comment: I wouldnt think to use other than datareaders in AS400. But the question was the top layer (UI) to use datasets to read and write to the only SQL server table..I think i will go with DTO and datareaders...Thanks

Comment: In my previous comment, what I was meant to not to use ORM tools with DB2 as you will not find too much support if there are any problems.